# Galaxy Note GT-N7000 won't connect to Google apps on Wi-Fi

Tags: applications, wi-fi

My Samsung Galaxy Note says it's connected to my Wi-Fi at home, and I can get onto some websites.

Google Mail, Google Search and Google Maps are not connected, but all will work if I switch Wi-Fi off.

I have had this phone for 18 months trouble-free.

Comment: Can you open Google Play, and is able to download an app (when on wi-fi)?